# INNER JOIN ID with most recent date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, relational-database, greatest-n-per-group

– Price (**prodID**, date)
– Product (**prodID**, name)

Suppose we have the above table, how would I INNER JOIN these two tables if I wanted to select the ID of each product along with the most recent date in the Price table?

I have the following code and I am receiving a syntax error on the GROUP BY line.

```
SELECT Product.prodId, Price.price, Price."date"
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN Price 
    INNER JOIN(
    SELECT Price.price, max("date") as currentPrice)cp
GROUP BY Price.prodId
ON Product.prodID = Price.prodId
ORDER BY Product.prodID;
```

I think it has something to do with my nested INNER JOIN since it is my first time attempting to use it but cannot find the answer online.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. Please just keep the one that corresponds to your RDBMS, and remove the other.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the most efficient method is to join the tables and filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*, i.*
from product p
inner join price i 
    on  i.prodID = p.prodID
    and i.date = (
        select max(i1.date) from price i1 where i1.prodID = i.prodID
    )
```

For performance, you want an index on `price(prodID, date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are other ways to express this query, you have started down the path of a separate subquery to get the maximum date.  The correct syntax looks like this:

```
SELECT p.prodId, pr.price, pr."date"
FROM Product p INNER JOIN
     Price  pr
     ON p.prodID = pr.prodId JOIN
     (SELECT pr2.prodId, max("date") as max_date
      FROM Price pr2
      GROUP BY pr2.prodId
     ) cp
     ON pr2.prodId = pr.prodID and pr2.max_date = pr.date
ORDER BY p.prodID;
```

Your query is just way-off.  The `GROUP BY` should be in the subquery, which is missing a `FROM` clause, for instance.